# Select rows in one DataFrame based on rows in another

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have a very large pandas DataFrame `dfBig` with columns `Param1, Param2, ..., ParamN, score, step`, and a smaller DataFrame `dfSmall` with columns `Param1, Param2, ..., ParamN` (i.e. missing the `score` and `step` columns).

I want to select all the rows of `dfBig` for which the values of columns `Param1, Param2, ..., ParamN` match those of some row in `dfSmall`. Is there a clean way of doing this in pandas?

**Edit:** To give an example, consider this DataFrame `dfBig`:

```
Arch  | Layers | Score | Time
A     | 1      | 0.3   | 10
A     | 1      | 0.6   | 20
A     | 1      | 0.7   | 30
A     | 2      | 0.4   | 10
A     | 2      | 0.5   | 20
A     | 2      | 0.6   | 30
B     | 1      | 0.1   | 10
B     | 1      | 0.2   | 20
B     | 1      | 0.7   | 30
B     | 2      | 0.7   | 10
B     | 2      | 0.8   | 20
B     | 2      | 0.8   | 30
```

Let's imagine a model is specified by a pair `(Arch, Layers)`. I want to query `dfBig` and get the time series for scores over time for the best performing models with Arch A and Arch B.

Following EdChum's answer below, I take it that the best solution is to do something like this procedurally:

```
modelColumns = [col for col in dfBigCol if col not in ["Time", "Score"]]    
groupedBest = dfBig.groupby("Arch").Score.max()
dfSmall = pd.DataFrame(groupedBest).reset_index()[modelColumns]
dfBest = pd.merge(dfSmall, dfBig)
```

which yields:

```
Arch  | Layers | Score | Time
A     | 1      | 0.3   | 10
A     | 1      | 0.6   | 20
A     | 1      | 0.7   | 30
B     | 2      | 0.7   | 10
B     | 2      | 0.8   | 20
B     | 2      | 0.8   | 30
```

If there's a better way to do this, I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you post a small sample of what you want to achieve and also define what match means

Comment: EdChum: I've added some details in the post. Thanks for your help thus far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you should be able to just call `merge` on `dfBig` and pass `dfSmall` which will look for matches in the aligned columns and only return those rows.

Example:

```
In [71]:

dfBig = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(100), 'b':np.arange(100), 'c':np.arange(100)})
dfSmall = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4,5,6]})
dfBig.merge(dfSmall)
Out[71]:
   a  b  c
0  3  3  3
1  4  4  4
2  5  5  5
3  6  6  6
```

Comment: Yes, I'm an idiot. A few minutes after posting this I thought "this sounds like an SQL merge" and google pandas merge. Thanks for the answer!